# Connecting site to AWS RDS results in HTTP Error 500

Tags: 7

I've moved my Drupal website over to AWS (using an EC2 instance and RDS instance). Everything moved over just fine. However, when I try and connect my drupal installation to my RDS database via the `settings.php` file, I get the following message when I navigate to my site IP:

> This page isn’t working [public ip] is currently unable to handle this request. HTTP ERROR 500

Right now, I'm putting my RDS endpoint into the settings.php file's 'host' spot.

```
$databases = array (
  'default' => 
  array (
    'default' => 
    array (
      'database' => 'mydbname',
      'username' => 'mydbusername',
      'password' => 'mypassword',
      'host' => 'myrdsendpoint.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com',
      'port' => '3306',
      'driver' => 'mysql',
      'prefix' => '',
    ),
  ),
);
```

When I leave the host blank, I do however get a Drupal error (as I should). That said, why am I unable to connect to the AWS RDS endpoint? I've even given my EC2 instance's private IP permission to access MySQL in the RDS' security group.

**Something to note**: When I do a fresh drupal install with the same above specs in the settings.php file, the new drupal site works perfectly (is visible). Could the 500 error be because my instance isn't large enough (e.g. do I need more space or memory?)

Help.

Comment: Without knowing the actual error this will be difficult to debug.

Comment: Well if a fresh install works perfectly then your issue is not an RDS connection problem. You can try clearing the cache via Drush, this may fix your problem. If still no dice, via command line you will have to look at your web server's logs, apache error logs or nginx error log to see what the error is.